# Tableview not setting right information in the column

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Good morning all, at the moment I run into this error with my code:
unchecked generic array creation for varargs parameter

```
TableView<Persoon> tableView = new TableView<>();
ObservableList<Persoon> myObservableList = FXCollections.observableList(zvcvolkel.getPersonen());

TableColumn<Persoon, String> voorNaamColumn = new TableColumn<>("Voornaam");
voorNaamColumn.setMinWidth(75);
voorNaamColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("voornaam"));

TableColumn<Persoon, String> tussenVoegselColumn = new TableColumn<>("Tussenvoegsel");
tussenVoegselColumn.setMinWidth(75);
tussenVoegselColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("tussenvoegsel"));

tableView.setItems(myObservableList);
tableView.getColumns().addAll(voorNaamColumn, tussenVoegselColumn);

GridPane root = new GridPane();
root.setHgap(10);
root.setVgap(12);

HBox view = new HBox();
view.setSpacing(10.0);

view.getChildren().add(tableView);
root.add(view, 1, 0);

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
Stage stage = new Stage();

stage.getIcons().add(new Image("Files/zvcvolkelicon.jpg"));
stage.setTitle("Leden");
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

It worked when I used 1 column, but when I added the second one the information of the second on displays in the first one and the other is left blank.

What am I missing out on?

Persoon class:

```
    package ZVCVolkel_Logic;

    public abstract class Persoon implements Comparable<Persoon>{

        private String voornaam;
        private String tussenvoegsel;
        private String achternaam;
        private String woonplaats;
        private String geslacht;
        private String rekeningnr;

        Persoon(String voornaam, String tussenvoegsel, String achternaam, String woonplaats,
                       String geslacht, String rekeningnr){
            this.voornaam = voornaam;
            this.tussenvoegsel = tussenvoegsel;
            this.achternaam = achternaam;
            this.woonplaats = woonplaats;
            this.geslacht = geslacht;
            this.rekeningnr = rekeningnr;
        }


        public String getVoornaam() {
            return voornaam;
        }

        public String getTussenvoegsel() {
            return tussenvoegsel;
        }

        public String getAchternaam() {
            return achternaam;
        }

        public String getWoonplaats() {
            return woonplaats;
        }

        public String getGeslacht() {
            return geslacht;
        }

        public String getRekeningnr() {
            return rekeningnr;
        }
```

Comment: That's an error? Or a warning? Can you post your `Persoon` class?

Comment: It's a warning, I've added the class

Comment: It looks like the info should be properly displayed. Are you sure your `Persoon` subclasses use the constructor correctly and `zvcvolkel.getPersonen()` uses your class correctly?

Comment: What you describe sounds like a copy-and-paste error (i.e. you have `voorNaamColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("tussenvoegsel"));` instead of `tussenVoegselColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("tussenvoegsel"));`). You don't have that in the code you posted here, but perhaps in the real code...?